# How do I write a Linq2Sql query that constrains rows with a collection of composite keys or tuples?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, expression-trees, composite-key

I'd like to write a Linq query (SQL backend) that constrains rows by a collection of values from several columns.  To illustrate, a naive SQL query might look like this, if I knew all the values up-front:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2 AND col2 = val3)
OR (col1 = val4 AND col2 = val5 AND col2 = val5)
OR (col1 = val6 AND col2 = val7 AND col2 = val8)
-- etc...
```

If I were writing this in SQL, I would consider using a join against a temp table, table valued parameter, or similar construct.  How would I accomplish this with Linq2Sql?  My values are not stored in another table, are computed from code and user input, and generally not known in advance -- I receive them as a collection of tuples.

I know that I can't join against in-memory collections without loading the entire table into memory first, and in those cases am limited to using `Contains`, resulting in a `WHERE ... IN` clause.  Is it possible to use this technique for composite keys and tuples?

Alternatively, I could manually build the expression tree for the `WHERE` clause emulating the `WHERE ... OR` clause in my example above.  Is there a better way?  I suspect that such a SQL statement will not be very efficient when there are hundreds of `OR` statements in the clause.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
var list = from mT in context.MyTables
           where (mT.col1 == val1 && mT.col2 == val2 && mT.col3 == val3)
           || (mT.col4 == val4 && mT.col5 == val5 && mT.col6 == val6)
           // etc etc
           select mT;
```

...where val1..val6 etc are local variables. This is a pretty direct copy of the 'naïve' SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question (I'll edit) -- I really don't know all the values in advance as they are passed to a function as a collection.

Comment: You mean you're getting something like a List<T> of unknown size at compile time? And you need to match the xth of the list to colX?

Comment: Yes, imagine that the collection is of type `List<Tuple<int, int, int>>`.  Now I need to create a predicate for each element in the list as follows: `where (mt.Col1 == list[0].Item1 && mt.Col2 == list[0].Item2 && mt.Col3 == list[0].Item3) || ( /* repeat for list[i] */ ...)`

I can create a loop and build an expression tree to do this, but I am curious if there is a simpler way.

Comment: I cam imagine that there might be another way, but I can't actually see it. If there is a way, I think it would be pretty complex code and hard to understand or maintain and so not very desirable. I'd go with the expression tree, if you've got that working.